# How to find the minimum value in between two values using R

Tags: r

In a column of data I am trying to identify the minimum value in between a new high and the previous new high. In the example below I marked where the new highs are and what the minimum value is between them. What is the R formula to figure this out? In excel I would be able to do it using the match and max/min formula. I am not sure how to find the minimum value in a segment of a column in r.

```
data
    0 New High
-80
-160
-160
-160
-160
-160
-347
-351
-351
-444
-444
-444
43 New High -444
43
10
10
-6
20
352 New High -6
352
352
528 New High 352
528
511
511
518
472
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cummax` to calculate cumulative maximum until that row and create a new group whenever the current row's value is greater than previous `cummax` value. Within each group you can return the minimum value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(V1 > lag(cummax(V1), default = first(V1)))) %>%
  summarise(min_value = min(V1))

#  group min_value
#  <int>     <int>
#1     0      -444
#2     1        -6
#3     2       352
#4     3       472
```

This considers the last part as another group hence also returns minimum value in that part. You can remove the last row if it is not needed.

---

To apply for multiple columns, we can write a function and call it with `lapply` :

```
apply_fun <- function(data, col) {

col1 <- sym(col)
df %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(!!col1 > lag(cummax(!!col1), 
           default = first(!!col1)))) %>%
  summarise(min_value = min(!!col1))
}

result <- lapply(names(df), apply_fun, data = df)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(0L, -80L, -160L, -160L, -160L, -160L, -160L, 
-347L, -351L, -351L, -444L, -444L, -444L, 43L, 43L, 10L, 10L, 
-6L, 20L, 352L, 352L, 352L, 528L, 528L, 511L, 511L, 518L, 472L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -28L))
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I was not familiar with dplyr. Is there some way wrap this code in an apply function in base R to make it do the calculation on a million different columns? Something like apply(df,2,function (x) {df %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(x > lag(cummax(x), default = first(x)))) %>%
  summarise(min_value = min(x)}))

Comment: @Eric Instead of `apply(df, 2.....` I think it is better to use `lapply`. See updated answer if that helps.